# Breaking out of one for loop and continuing the other code

Tags: python, for-loop, break

I currently have an excel sheet checking another excel sheet for certain numbers. Once it finds the matching cell, I want it to move on back to the very first for loop. if it doesn't find the matching cell, but finds the first 6 digits of it, I want it to mark it as checked and then move back to the first for loop again.

How is this done?

Below is my code. I commented where I wanted it to go back to the first `for` loop I made.

```
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    cell = str(sheet.cell_value(row, 0))
    if fd.match(cell):
        for rows in range(sheet.nrows):
            windcell = str(windc_sheet.cell_value(rows, 0))
            if fd.match(windcell):
                if cell == windcell:
                    outputsheet.write(row, 1, ' ')
                    #GO BACK TO FIRST FOR LOOP

                else:
                    sixdig = cell[0:6]
                    sixdigwind = windcell[0:6]
                    if sixdig == sixdigwind:
                        outputsheet.write(row, 1, 'Check')
                        #GO BACK TO FIRST FOR LOOP

    else:
        sixdig = cell[0:6]
        for rows in range(sheet.nrows):
            windcell = str(windc_sheet.cell_value(rows,0))
            sixdigwind = windcell[0:6]
            if sixdig == sixdigwind:
                outputsheet.write(row, 1, 'Check')
```

Comment: Use the `break` statement.

Comment: use operator break

Comment: Where do you want execution to continue? "Move" or "go back" to the "first for" is a little unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `break` statement. It breaks you out of a `for` loop or `while` loop.

From the Python docs:

> break may only occur syntactically nested in a for or while loop, but not
>   nested in a function or class definition within that loop. **It terminates the
>   nearest enclosing loop**, skipping the optional else clause if the loop has one.
>   If a for loop is terminated by break, the loop control target keeps its current
>   value. When break passes control out of a try statement with a finally clause,
>   that finally clause is executed before really leaving the loop.

(Emphasis mine)

```
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    cell = str(sheet.cell_value(row, 0))
    if fd.match(cell):
        for rows in range(sheet.nrows):
            windcell = str(windc_sheet.cell_value(rows, 0))
            if fd.match(windcell):
                if cell == windcell:
                    outputsheet.write(row, 1, ' ')
                    break  # TERMINATE ENCLOSING FOR LOOP

                else:
                    sixdig = cell[0:6]
                    sixdigwind = windcell[0:6]
                    if sixdig == sixdigwind:
                        outputsheet.write(row, 1, 'Check')
                        break  # TERMINATE ENCLOSING FOR LOOP

    else:
        sixdig = cell[0:6]
        for rows in range(sheet.nrows):
            windcell = str(windc_sheet.cell_value(rows,0))
            sixdigwind = windcell[0:6]
            if sixdig == sixdigwind:
                outputsheet.write(row, 1, 'Check')
```